# How to set more width for ChartWidget on dashboard?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

On laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 site I make 'bar' report witch  extends ChartWidget, but resulted chart is rather narrow :
[image]

I would like to set more width for it, at least at full width.

a) But looking at vendor/filament/widgets/src/ChartWidget.php I did not find any options to tune it. Can I do it?

b) I tried to set width to parent div, I suppose class path must be like :

```
col-[--col-span-default] fi-wi-widget fi-wi-chart
```

But how can I set custom css?
Also I would prefer to set custom css by unique ID, to apply this css to only 1 widget, but not to all widgets of the appp.

How can I do it ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.28.0",
"filament/filament": "^3.0-stable",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [the document](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/dashboard#customizing-the-widgets-grid), you can customize the size of widgets by overriding the `$columnSpan` property.

So to make it a full-width chart, you can add the below line to your chart widget:

```php
    protected int | string | array $columnSpan = 'full';
```